# Index templates in Spring Data ElasticSearch, how?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've read https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/24/spring-data-2020-0-new-and-noteworthy-in-spring-data-elasticsearch-4-1 that index template was implemented.

But searching `index temp` in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html found nothing but saying that it is supported.

Can someone share an example?

Thanks.